# Additional factors in determining probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Say we have 3 types of items for purchase in a bakery: donuts, cakes, and cookies.
There are 9 items total, a chocolate, vanilla, and strawberry of each type.

The 9 items are divided among 3 people, A, B, and C, so each gets 3 total.

These following 2 questions appear to ask the same thing.

1) Person D sees that Person A has at least one donut.  What is the probability, as a fourth person D observes, that Person A has at least another donut?

2) Person D sees that Person A has a chocolate donut.  As person D observes, What is the probability that person A has at least another donut?

I am just wondering if in this case, the flavor truly matters.  Regardless, we know that Person A has at least one donut, and shouldn't we be able to determine the same result?
I can't tell if Person D's perspective makes some type of difference, or if this is a bit of a trick question.
Any helpful hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

D's perspective makes difference.

1.) If A has one donut. It can be any of 3 flavours. So we have 6 cases for donuts.

2.) If A has chocolate donut then we have only 2 cases for other donuts.

And your both questions contain at least so there are many other cases.

Comment: Right, but in the first scenario, Person D knows that Person A has at least one donut, and there are 2 remaining.  In the second scenario, Person D knows that Person A has a chocolate donut, and that there are still 2 remaining.  So why does this make a difference?

Comment: Suppose chocolate donut is cd, vanilla donut is cd and strawberry donut is sd. So A has one donut it can be any so we have cases {(sd, vd, cd),(sd, cd, vd), (cd, vd, sd), ... total 6 cases.

Comment: In other case A has cd then cases {(cd, sd, vd), (cd, vd, sd)}. Total 2 cases.